# Numbers and percentage

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, real-numbers

When x is decreased by 15% and then increased by 20%, it becomes y. How to find this value of y? Express x:y in its simplest form

The first step I done was to take away 15% from X which becomes 85% , how to do the next 20%?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You have:
$$
y=x(1-15\%)(1+20\%)
$$
because the value incremented by $20\%$ is $x(1-15\%)$.